# Dynamic cast in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, overloading

I'm not sure if this is what it's called, but here is the problem:

I have a superclass with three subclasses.
Let's say Superclass, Subclass1, Subclass2,Subclass3

I have another class with the following overloaded method:

```
public void exampleMethod (Subclass1 object1){
//Method to be called if the object is of subclass 1
}

public void exampleMethod (Subclass2 object2){
//Method to be called if the object is of subclass 2
}

public void exampleMethod (Subclass3 object3){
//Method to be called if the object is of subclass 3
}
```

Is there a way for me to call the overloaded method from the superclass while dynamically casting the method parameter to the object type at runtime?

```
anotherClass.exampleMethod(this);
```

Comment: There is a similar question here with a working answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281293/java-dynamic-casting-for-overloaded-methods

Comment: Could the required cast be done using reflections maybe? I don't know myself since I only have a vague idea of what reflections are, but that would be where I would start looking for a solution.

Comment: You can use factory design pattern for your this purpose It will simplify your logic as well as code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (this instanceof Subclass1) {
    anotherClass.exampleMethod((Subclass1)this);
} else if (this instanceof Subclass2) {
    anotherClass.exampleMethod((Subclass2)this);
}
...
```

Is that what you mean?

Probably better to do

```
abstract class Superclass {
    abstract void callExampleMethod(AnotherClass anotherClass);
}

class Subclass1 extends Superclass {
    void callExampleMethod(AnotherClass anotherClass) {
        anotherClass.exampleMethod(this);
    }
}
... same for other subclasses ...
```

You can then call `callExampleMethod` in the superclass, and it will delegate properly.

Comment: Nope, that fails for all subclasses but one. -1

Comment: Well, yes, you would need to use `instanceof` to condition the subclass.  I was assuming that was clear...

Comment: +1 since I don't think misunderstanding a question deserves a downvote.

Comment: @G.Bach I've removed my downvote *because* the answer is now much better than back when I downvoted. But I beg to differ on the matter of downvoting misunderstandings of the question. A vote is not a statement about the poster or his intents, just about the answer in its current shape and in the context of the question. If the answer is useful for the question at hand, it should be upvoted. If it's not useful, or actively harmful (e.g. wrong), it should be downvoted, even if Gandhi posted it.

Comment: @MiserableVariable Yes, sorry about that. Fixed it.

Comment: This is what I currently have implemented. But it felt a bit clunky to me, since any change done will need to be done to every single subclass implementing this method. But I guess it's still the right way to do it.. And I would really like to avoid a chain of instanceof.

Comment: @delnan I disagree that the answer in its original form merited a downvote. It was phrased as a question asking (with code as an illustration) whether Keith Randall understood the question of OP correctly. As such, it showed that it was more an initial "draft" and less a final answer. I agree that answers that are not open for changing their content if it requires such a change should be downvoted; I disagree that that was the case here.

Comment: @G.Bach That's nice on your part, but most "how about ... ?" style answers I see are posted by clueless persons who never return to the question. **Comments** are for such queries. If you post an answer, I expect that you *know* what you're talking about, or go by a reasonable assumption. Also see what meta has to say on this: [To Downvote or Not to Downvote…or to Wait?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112659/to-downvote-or-not-to-downvote-or-to-wait).