# Dynamically cast to subclass to use correct method overload

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm trying to make my code more polymorphic.  Right now I have a superclass that has four different subclasses.  I have a method that accepts the superclass as a type.  I want to perform some generic actions before routing it to a different method to handle other actions.  Here's what I am envisioning:

```
public void performSomething(Super object) { 
    //do some generic action each time to object
    object.setSuperProperty();

    //now route to appropriate method to perform specific action
    doSpecific(object);
}

private void doSpecific(SubA object) { }

private void doSpecific(SubB object) { }

private void doSpecific(SubC object) { }

private void doSpecific(SubD object) { }
```

This way if I want to add more functionality -- by creating a new subclass or whatever -- then I just need to add another method with the correct subclass type.  However, this is not possible since the compiler complains about not having a `doSpecific(Super object)` method.  Instead, in `performSomething(Super object)` I have to do an ugly:

```
if(object instanceof SubA)
    doSpecific((SubA)object);
else if(object instanceof SubB)
    doSpecific((SubB)object);
...
```

Is there a better way to do this than having to perform all the `instanceof` checks?  Is there a design pattern that I'm not thinking of?  I know that I'll lose the compile-time type check safety, but just curious what other solutions could possibly exist.

edit: Forgot to mention this.  `performSomething` and `doSpecific` are part of an unrelated class I'll call `ClassA`.  I considered creating an abstract method in the Super class so that the subclass could properly implement it.  The problem is that `performSomething` and `doSpecific` depend on roughly 8 different members of `ClassA`.  So if I wanted to delegate the method to the subclass it would require a ton of parameters like `subB.doSpecific(int, int, String, String, Object, int, long, blah, blah);` which I'm not sure is better than the original `instanceOf` check.  This would also create a tight coupling between `ClassA` and the `Super/Sub` classes I have, when doesn't seem right since I just need to read values from them.

Comment: Hmm, this just popped up in the related which is interesting, but seems tightly coupled and would have to expose as a public method to call: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924617/dynamic-cast-in-java?rq=1

Comment: Where are `performSomething` and `doSpecific`?

Comment: What about `doCommon(Super s)`, code reuse, and `performSomething(SubA a)`, polymorphism?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

That means: Every of your subclasses implements a `doSpecific()` method. Then your initial method looks like this:

```
public void performSomething(Super object) { 
    //do some generic action each time to object
    object.setSuperProperty();

    //now route to appropriate method to perform specific action
    object.doSpecific(...);
}
```

The compiler picks the method of the subclass automatically - no `instanceOf` check for you.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned this in my main post. I have too many member variables that doSomething depends on. I would have to pass 8-9 arguments doing it this way.